# custom post type 'pre_[cpt]_query' hook

Tags: wp-user-query

When quering the wordpress users table, is it possible to use '[pre_user_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/)' to ammend the SQL query before execution against the database. Is there an equivalent hook method for each registered custom post type?

I'm using the [posts 2 posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to link two groups of custom post types. I want to include details of the number of p2p links in the basic queries for each post, so that i can page based on the number of links.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 1):

WP doesn't provide (as far as I remember) hooks *specific* to CPTs. There are *a lot* of hooks in `WP_Query` class to bend the post queries different ways. In most cases they are passed the query object itself, which is used to derive the context (such as is query for specific post type).